# Is it possible to accept a List<Guid> as a paramater from checkboxes in Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, modelbinders

I know its possible to accept a list of objects as a parameter [thanks to haacked](http://haacked.com/archive/0001/01/01/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) but what about a list of Guids from checkboxes? This is a bit different as the only name you get has to be the ID.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can do Guids this way, since they don't expose a public setter property. I would suggest doing a List and then iterating over the list and using the Guid overload that takes a string:

```
public ActionResult Foo(IList<string> guidStrings) 
{
   var guids = new List<Guid>();
   foreach(var s in guidStrings)
   {
   guid.Add(new Guid(s));
   }

   return View(guidStrings);
}
```

Or something like that...

Comment: The issue isn't with List<Guid> but rather whether how it detects the information. If these were simply hidden fields or textboxes, it wouldn't be a problem. But because Checkboxes have 1 name (in this case, it would need to be the value of the Guid) and the value is true/false (or actually, nothing as unchecked boxes don't get pushed back) I don't know if its possible to accept the list.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying now. My bad, didn't understand the question. I'll code up some quick samples, and see if I can come up with something.

Comment: Thanks and sorry about the confusion. I'm attempting to do it simply with the form collection but for some strange reason <%=Html.Checkbox(value, bool) not only spits out a checkbox but also a hidden field with the value?

Comment: So they did some funky stuff.. ended up writing my own html
                <input type="checkbox" name="selectedCategories[<%=i %>]" value="<%=category.ID%>" <%=checkedText %> />                 <label for="<%=category.ID %>"><%=category.Name %></label>